# Search for anything inside certain elements

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

I feel like this must be simple, but I can't find any answer online.

I want to search for anything that is within an element with a particular class using Notepad++.

So I want to find all instances of `<div class="ex">blahablahablah</div>`, doesn't matter what is between the divs. I want to be able to do a find and replace for these so that I can bulk delete.

Comment: What about other `div`s? Can they be between the `div`s you're looking for?

Comment: no, its always going to be a div with the same class and a varying text string between the open and close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div[^>]*>.*?</div>
```

or if you just want divs with `class="ex"` like above

```
<div class="ex">.*?</div>
```

Edit: if you want to have more attributes in your div besides class, but want to make sure it's a specific class, you could do it this way:

```
<div[^>]*?class="ex"[^>]*>.*?</div>
```

This would match all of the below:

```
<div class="ex">blah blah</div>
<div class="ex" id="blah">blah blah</div>
<div id="foo" class="ex">blah blah</div>
<div id="foo" class="ex" style="bar">blah blah</div>
```

I just re-read your question and it appears you are trying to replace only what is inside the element and not the entire element. If you wish to do that, you can do it like this:

Find what: `(<div[^>]*?class="ex"[^>]*>).*?(</div>)`
Replace with: `$1replaced$2`

Now all your divs of class `ex` will contain only "replaced"

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to replace the whole element with the div but I have wanted to change just what was inside before, so that is very helpful both ways. :)